# jQuery is there some way to set up an on "first click, whatever click" event

Tags: jquery, html

I have three buttons, each with a jquery on.click event.  In addition to the three things I want to happen with each of those events, I want a click -- whichever click the user chooses -- to render a bit of html.  jQuery .one doesn't help, because  I don't know which button the user will choose.  And I do not want the first button click event to be disabled after it is clicked (ie you can click again).  I have tried hide /unhide the html, but it shows for split second at page load which is not ideal.  I am beginning programmer so do not know what else to try.  Many thanks for any help.

```
boxOne.on('click', soundOne)
   function soundOne(e) {
      var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
      url: ''
      });
      mySound.play();
      results.append('<li>' + "text" '<li>');
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked);
    }
```

Let's say I have five of these boxes/click events. In addition to playing the url sound and appending some text, I would like the FIRST of these clicks (and it doesn't matter which one it is, but I don't KNOW which "box" will be clicked first) to render a heading on the page.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code or an example on jsfiddle...

Comment: Sounds like two separate issues: first reacting on the first click, second reliably hiding some elements from the start on.

Comment: can you add a class or ID to your `results.append('<li>' + "text" '<li>');` to look like `results.append('<li id="resId">' + "text" '<li>');` then before you do anything in your function make sure that `if ($('#resId').length == 0) { //do stuff } else { // do nothing }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some css class for selector and a counter.

Lets said you add the `box` class to your five elements

```
$(".box") // This is an array with 5 elements, the 5 boxes.
```

Bind the click event to that array, using the `.click()` handler of jQuery, and outside of that scope declare a variable to count the clicks of the user. It should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0 //the number of clicks
    $(".box").click(function(){
        if( counter == 0) { // the first click
            //do some stuff
        }

        // rest of your code
        counter++; // keep counting clicks!
    })
})
```